# EXC_BAD_ACCESS on function - iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, exc-bad-access

I am trying to implement this [library](https://github.com/PowerMobileWeb/TGLAugmentedRealityView) but I have a weird issue. I get

> EXC_BAD_ACCESS

error on this function:

```
- (void)setUserLocation:(CLLocation *)userLocation {

    if (userLocation) {

        _userLocation = userLocation;

        [self updatePlaceOverlayPositions];
    }
}
```

The debugger shows that the error is on this line:

```
- (void)setUserLocation:(CLLocation *)userLocation {
```

The thing is that I don't know where this function is called from. When I control click on the name of the function, it prompts me to the .h file of the class on this line:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) CLLocation *userLocation;
```

Those are the delegates I use for the class:

```
<CLLocationManagerDelegate, TGLARViewDataSource, TGLARViewDelegate, PlaceOfInterestViewDelegate>
```

but this function is nowhere inside them.

When I run the example of this project, there is no error. But for some reason when I try to implement this library inside my project this error occurs.

If you have any idea of how to debug this error I will appreciate it.

Comment: did you used for this library?

Comment: First of all set the Exception Breakpoint to get more information about the crash.

Comment: @vadian I used Exception Breakpoints but I didn't get any info.

Comment: @KKRocks what do you mean?

Comment: Menas use the library using pod.
Follow steps which are given : https://github.com/PowerMobileWeb/TGLAugmentedRealityView

Comment: When the crash occurs click on the `continue` button in the debug console area.

Comment: @vadian I do, nothing happens.